# How to install nvidia optimus graphics card driver in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I have a laptop with nvidia optimus graphics card.I have successfully installed its driver in windows 7. When I tried to install its driver in ubuntu 13 it failed.I need to install the driver so that I can use the specific features of this card(Power saving option).How can I install nvidia optimus driver in ubuntu? please help me ..